# Is there a way to set the acks_late config in Celery?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, django-celery

For my Django project, I am using Celery with Redis, registering the tasks on runtime using the `celery_app.tasks.register` method. I want to retrigger a task in case of some failure, I have set the acks_late config param using `task_acks_late=True` on the app level while instantiating celery itself. I have also set `task_reject_on_worker_lost=True`. However, the tasks aren't being received back by celery no matter what. Is there any other way?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution, @karthi keyan?

Comment: @pdoherty926 Nope, haven't found any feasible solution, apparently, with these settings, we should be able to achieve a retrigger, but for some reason, it's not. This item is currently in my backlog and I shall look into upgrading my celery versions if it helps or use RabbitMQ as backend instead of Redis.